# SQL creating and populating

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

Could anyone experienced have a quick look at the following. I am not smart enough to resolve the system error just yet.

```sql
CREATE TABLE TestSubject (

test_subjectID      NCHAR (6)   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
subject_name            NVARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
subject_address     NVARCHAR (12)   NOT NULL,
)
;
CREATE TABLE PhNumber (

subject_id      NCHAR (6)   NOT NULL,
ph_number       NVARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (ph_number),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES TestSubject (test_subjectID)
);


CREATE TABLE Test (

test_date       DATETIME    NOT NULL,
subject_id      NCHAR (6)   NOT NULL,
result          NVARCHAR (10),

PRIMARY KEY (test_date),

FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES TestSubject (test_subjectID));

CREATE TABLE Place (

place_name      NVARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
place_address       NVARCHAR (8),
place_owner     NVARCHAR (8)
);

CREATE TABLE VisitSubject (

v_date          DATETIME    NOT NULL,
v_number        NVARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
place_visit     NVARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
party_size      INT,

PRIMARY KEY (v_date),

FOREIGN KEY (v_number) REFERENCES PhNumber (ph_number),
FOREIGN KEY (place_visit) REFERENCES Place (place_name));
```

And the populate script

```sql
INSERT INTO TestSubject
VALUES 
('S001', 'Daniel Doppler', '5 Beetle Avenue Aberdeen'),
('S002', 'Florence West', '17 Green Crescent Dundee'),
('S003', 'Werner Flick', '25A Grubb Street Stonehaven'),
('S004', 'Tiffany Smith', '11 Green Crescent Dundee'),
('S005', 'Angela Ashe', '113 Wasp Street Aberdeen');


INSERT INTO Test
VALUES
('2020/08/05 00:00:00', 'S001', 'Negative'),
('2020/08/10 00:00:00', 'S002', 'Positive'),
('2020/08/17 00:00:00', 'S003', 'Negative'),
('2020/08/22 00:00:00', 'S004', 'Negative'),
('2020/08/22 00:00:00', 'S005', 'Negative'),
('2020/09/03 00:00:00', 'S001', 'Positive');

INSERT INTO PhNumber
VALUES
('S001', '07123-123456'),
('S002', '07777-111000'),
('S003', '07555-246810'),
('S004', '07101-484848'),
('S004', '07896-102304'),
('S005', '07777-534242');

INSERT INTO Place
VALUES
('Pink Lion Inn', 'Forfar', 'Sean Conran'),
('Irenes Hair Salon', 'Stonehaven', 'Irene Jones');

INSERT INTO VisitSubject
VALUES
('2020/08/01 00:00:00', '07123-123456', 'Irenes Hair Salon', '1'),
('2020/08/01 00:00:00', '07777-111000', 'Irenes Hair Salon', '2'),
('2020/08/25 00:00:00', '07123-123456', 'Pink Lion Inn', '4'),
('2020/08/25 00:00:00', '07493-285113', 'Pink Lion Inn', '2'),
('2020/09/10 00:00:00', '07555-246810', 'Irenes Hair Salon', '1'),
('2020/09/15 00:00:00', '07555-246810', 'Pink Lion Inn', '3');
```

I cannot populate the existing tables because of 2 errors -

> String or binary data would be truncated

and

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Test__subject_id__286302EC". The conflict occurred in database "TAT_2012552", table "dbo.TestSubject", column 'test_subjectID'.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__PhNumber__subjec__25869641". The conflict occurred in database "TAT_2012552", table "dbo.TestSubject", column 'test_subjectID'.

Comment: What about the errors don't you understand? Certainly the first one is very clear, the latter  are too, but due to you choosing to not name your constraints makes harder to tell what constraint is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The first error means that you are trying to insert a value in a column where the data type length is smaller than the value. For example, in your `VisitSubject` table, the `place_visit` column can accept strings that have 10 characters or less. In your case, for example, value ***Irenes Hair Salon*** cannot be inserted because it's more than 10 characters.

The second error is thrown because `subject_id` values inserted in your tables `Test` and `PhNumber` are not existing in the table `TestSubject`. And why it is not existing in your table `TestSubject` ? Because SQL couldn't insert any row in this table because `subject_name` and `subject_address` values inserted have more characters than the data type length defined in your table.

Please first solve issue about inserting values longer than the data types definitions, and it should solve your foreign key issues then.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much for the response. I am just not there yet:)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the obvious error:

> String or binary data would be truncated

This error is very much telling you the problem, you have a string value that is trying to be inserted into a column, however, it is too large and as such the value would be truncated. As a result the `INSERT` statement fails. If you're on a more recent version of SQL Server, you actually get even more verbose errors for this. There are actually 3 of these errors in your batch, such as:

> String or binary data would be truncated in table 'YourDatabase.dbo.TestSubject', column 'subject_name'. Truncated value: 'Daniel Dop'.

Clearly you aren't using the latest version of SQL Server, or you would have shared that whole error, however, the old error do still tell you what table and column the error is on.

So let's have a look at the column `YourDatabase.dbo.TestSubject.subject_name`, which is defined as a `nvarchar(10)`. Well looking at the `INSERT`, the first person's name is `'Daniel Doppler'`, which is more than 10 characters and hence the error. In fact, the entire `INSERT` statement will fail for ***every*** string value, as your `subject_address` column is defined as an `nvarchar(12)`, yet the first value you try to `INSERT` is `'5 Beetle Avenue Aberdeen'` which is *way* more than 12 characters.

So how do you fix this? Fix your table's definition and increase the size of the columns; clearly 10 and 12 characters are not enough for a "subject's" name and address respectively.

---

So, what about the other errors such as:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Test__subject_id__29572725". The conflict occurred in database "YourDatabase", table "dbo.TestSubject", column 'test_subjectID'.

Well, this is actually a result of your prior error; your `INSERT` failed as you're trying to `INSERT` data that is too large for your columns and thus it isn't `INSERT`ed. Then, when you get to the next `INSERT` statement the Foreign Key constraint (which has an obtuse name as you didn't give it one, but we'll come to that in a second) fails it's `CHECK` as there are no rows in the table `dbo.TestSubject`. Effectively the prior truncation error just compounds the problem.

---

As I mentioned, these errors happen multiple times, you have 3 truncation errors in that batch; meaning 3 `INSERT` statements fail due to the column being too small for the value to fit; you'll need to fix each of those tables definition so that they are an appropriate length for the data you are inserting. You also have 2 Foreign Key constrait failures, but these will likely disappear when you fix the table definitions.

---

As I mentioned, I do, however, recommend naming your constraints. You can do this by using an `ALTER` statement and creating the `CONSTRAINT` in there instead. For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.PhNumber (subject_id nchar(6) NOT NULL,
                           ph_number nvarchar(20) NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE dbo.PhNumber ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PhNumber PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ph_number);
ALTER TABLE dbo.PhNumber ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PhNumber_TestSubject FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES dbo.TestSubject (test_subjectID);
```

This changes one the errors, about the Foreign Key failure, to the below; which is must more understandable due to the key's name:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_PhNumber_TestSubject". The conflict occurred in database "YourDatabase", table "dbo.TestSubject", column 'test_subjectID'.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your patience and such a brilliant detailed answer. I have presumably fixed the string length, added constraints, but I still keep getting errors.

Comment: For example, CREATE TABLE TestSubject (

test_subjectID  NCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
subject_name   NVARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
subject_address  NVARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_TestSubject PRIMARY KEY (test_subjectID) 
); The constraint line keeps saying that 'Table level constraint does not specify column list, table TestSubject'. I vaguely understand what the problem is about, but non of the solutions I had tried, worked:(

Comment: *" but I still keep getting errors"* that doesn't tell me anything. Really, however, you need to debug those errors yourself as you should have done with the first ones. The errors are *telling you* the problem. Read the errors, and then address the problems they are telling you about. Don't see an errors, and immediately ask for help, you learn far more by actually trying. [so] isn't a support forum, it's a Q&A website; the users aren't here to answer follow on questions and are under no obligation to. We're address the question at hand, and if they results in a new question, post a new one.

Comment: That's ok. Thank you